# Low Performance When Using Backplane in SignalR in ASP.NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET Framework 4.8 application, and I use the AspNet.SignalR library. Here's a brief context for the reason behind its usage:

The application is for an ERP, and some clients use devices such as card terminals, printers, etc. These devices communicate with the client's machine, not the server. So, we use a communication hub to interact with an exe on the client's machine.

So far, so good. However, recently, there was a change in the client servers. An adjustment was made to increase the number of processes in the IIS pool, and everything stopped working. After some research, I found that I needed to implement a backplane. I implemented it using SQL Server and Redis. However, for some reason, the performance is much lower than when using it without the backplane. I'll provide a snippet of the code below to help you understand better.

Every time I try to process a transaction on the card terminal, it goes into this function:

```
        public async Task<DadosComunicacao> Conecta()
        {
            this.HubProxy = await RetornaConexao();
            this._tokenTransacao = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                await this._conexao.Start();
                await this.HubProxy.Invoke("entrarGrupo", this._nomeGrupo);

                if (this._dados.TipoComunicacao == TipoComunicacao.TEF)
                {
                    this._tokenTransacao = TokenHelper.GerarToken();
                    this._dados.TokenTransacao = this._tokenTransacao;
                }

                string envioJson = JsonHelper.SerializeObject(this._dados);

                if (!this._dados.TipoComunicacao.Equals(TipoComunicacao.POSStone))
                    await this.HubProxy.Invoke("enviarJson", envioJson, this._nomeGrupo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // return ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
            }

            //Instancia a o handler com o estado inicial dele falso é que ele sera resetado automaticamente
            this._waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

            //Começou a aguardar o retorno do windows forms - Gerenciador Web
            this.HubProxy.On("receberJson", (mensagem) =>
            {
                this._dados = JsonHelper.DeserializeObject<DadosComunicacao>(mensagem);

                //Seta o estado do handler para verdadeiro
                if (this._dados.TipoComunicacao == TipoComunicacao.TEF)
                {
                    if (this._dados.TokenTransacao == this._tokenTransacao)
                        this._waitHandle.Set();
                }
                else
                    this._waitHandle.Set();
            });

            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000); //Aguarda 30 seg

            if (this._dados.TipoComunicacao == TipoComunicacao.TEF)
                timer.Interval = 1200000; //Aguarda 20 min.
            else if (this._dados.TipoComunicacao.Equals(TipoComunicacao.POSStone))
                timer.Interval = 1200000;

            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

            //Task fica aguardando o estado do handler ser definido como verdadeiro.
            //Ao ter o método Set do handler chamado, a variável recebe o aviso e o processando continua
            await Task.Run(() => this._waitHandle.WaitOne());

            timer.Dispose();
            this._conexao.Dispose();

            return this._dados;
        }
```

Method that returns the hub proxy:

```
       public async Task<IHubProxy> RetornaConexao(bool entrarGrupo = false)
       {
           string url = string.Empty;

           if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this._urlWebHub))
           {
               url = string.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}/{3}", this._currentContext.Request.Url.Scheme,
                                                          this._currentContext.Request.Url.Host,
                                                          this._currentContext.Request.Url.Port,
                                                           UrlHelper.ResolveUrl("~/", this._currentContext));
           }
           else
               url = this._urlWebHub;

           this._conexao = new HubConnection(url);

           var proxy = this._conexao.CreateHubProxy("webhub"); //Classe com os métodos de comunicação

           if (entrarGrupo)
           {
               await this._conexao.Start();
               await proxy.Invoke("entrarGrupo", this._nomeGrupo);
           }

           return proxy;
       }
```

I tested the following backplanes:

Redis as a Windows service (I cannot use it with a Linux subsystem)
SQL Server Backplane
Note: I already tested activating the service broker of the database on SQL Server, using a higher tablecount, maxqueue, etc.

One thing I noticed while using SQL Profiler with the SQL Server backplane is that it makes several queries every time I try to transact. Can someone help me? Is there a metric I'm not aware of or some alternative solution I can explore?

Comment: My org recently switched from those "backplane" services to _Azure SignalR Service_  (specifically, from Azure ServiceBus) because of poor overall performance and surprisingly high running costs (like $80/mo when the estimate said ~$30/mo). I might suggest you give that a try.

Comment: We do not use Azure to host our applications; another cloud hosting service is employed. Therefore, I believe I cannot use that option.

Comment: Is your cloud-provider using Azure Stack? (i.e. private-label Azure)? If so, I believe there's a SignalR service buried in there, but you might have to ask for it